# Why does array_uintersect() compare elements between array1 & array2, array1 & array1, and array2 & array2?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, custom-function, array-intersect

Test script

```
$i = 0;
array_uintersect(['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux'], function($a, $b) use (&$i) {
    print_r([$a, $b, $i++]);
});
```

Actual Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => foo
    [2] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => qux
    [1] => baz
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => qux
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => foo
    [2] => 3
)
```

Expected Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => baz
    [2] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => qux
    [2] => 1
)
```

In other words, what I am expecting to be passed to the callback is the current element of the left array, and the current element of the right array.

Furthermore, I would expect the same logic to apply if I were to pass an additional array to `array_uintersect` - one more argument being passed to the callback (`$c`, for example).

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand your use of `$i` here. From the docs: "The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

Comment: @mistermartin I am using it for debugging purposes; a way to keep track on how much times does the iteration happen.

Comment: Why don't you just loop through the first array and use the same index to get the value from the second array?

Comment: @SanderVisser Sure, but I want to use this function so any developer that picks up on my work in the future immediately knows what's going on. Intersection is self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes but the `array_uintersect` tries to intersect the values not the key http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: PHP inconsistency in function naming but found it ;) php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-ukey.php But that isn't what you want. See my answer with array_map

Comment: So, you didn't actually show or ask what you are trying to do with an actual arrays, just a question about why `array_uintersect()` compares internally in such a way.  Not why it does a certain thing with your input arrays that you want. Do you have actual input and output arrays and need help?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm only interested in the behaviour of the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's not mentioned in the [`array_uintersect` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) is that, internally, [PHP *sorts* all the arrays](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L4099) first, left to right. Only *after* the arrays are sorted does PHP walk them (again, left to right) to find the intersection.

The third argument (the comparison function) is passed to the internal sort algorithm, not the intersecting algorithm. Thus, the debugging output seen is the sorting algorithm figuring out the ordering.

The [zend_sort implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_sort.c#L317) generally [uses a bisecting quick sort implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166119/2908724). For arrays of the size in your example, PHP uses insertion sort. For large arrays, PHP uses a 3 or 5 point pivot so as to [improve worst-case complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126947/2908724).

Since you're not explicitly returning any value from the comparison function, PHP defaults to returning null (0), and since PHP is using insertion sort, you're seeing O(n*n) behavior as the sort walks all the combinations.

Comment: Great answer, it's the one I was waiting for. Other people were trying to be helpful and score some reputation by providing workarounds, but my question was *why* is it behaving that way. I went through the C code you've linked, and to me, it seems that, internally, `array_uintersect` (`array_intersect` in general) is analogous with manually iterating over the array with `foreach` and checking if needle element exists in haystack array with `in_array()`, and the main difference being that the C code sorts it before iterating, thus increasing the lookup speed.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why do you expect anything from the comparison callback, except comparing the values of the arrays. The sole purpose of the callback is to compare the next pair of items from both arrays.

The function returns the result of intersection of the two arrays. In the callback you express your idea of how the values are supposed to be compared. For example, the following code assumes that the intersection should be performed by comparing the first characters of the strings:

```
$a = array_uintersect(['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux'], function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});

print_r($a);
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [1] => bar
)
```

The order of the items passed to the callback is specified by the PHP internals, and may easily change in future.

So the comparison function is not supposed to do anything, except comparing two variables. There is not even a hint of use of the callback for any other purpose in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first two calls are being used to seed variables in the internal algorithm.  But since you don't return anything that the algorithm can use to determine equality/sorting, it only runs the next two.

If you actually return `0`, `1` or `-1` then you see the full comparison chain that is needed to calculate the intersection:

```
$i = 0;
array_uintersect(['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux'], function($a, $b) use (&$i) {
    print_r([$a, $b, $i++]);

    if ($a === $b) return 0;
    if ($a  >  $b) return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => foo
    [2] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => qux
    [1] => baz
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => baz
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => baz
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => baz
    [2] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => qux
    [2] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this ;)

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    return [$a, $b];
}, ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux']);
var_dump($result);
```

This will output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "baz"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "qux"
  }
}
```

Update: It returns the result you want with the `array_uintersect` method. It isn't the most efficient way to do this and didn't test it with different data sets etc but should work.

```
$entities = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'timestamp' => 1234
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'timestamp' => 12345
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'timestamp' => 123456
    ],
    [
        'id' => 8,
        'timestamp' => 123456
    ],
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'timestamp' => 123456
    ],
    [
        'id' => 11,
        'timestamp' => 123456
    ],
    [
        'id' => 12,
        'timestamp' => 123456
    ]
];

$identities = [1, 11, 2, 8, 10];

$result = array_uintersect($entities, $identities, function($a, $b) {

    // Both array skip
    if (is_array($a) && is_array($b)) {
        if ($a['id'] > $b['id']) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Both int skip
    if (is_int($a) && is_int($b)) {
        if ($a > $b) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // $a is array
    if (is_array($a)) {
        if ($a['id'] == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        elseif ($a['id'] > $b) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // $b is array
    if($b['id'] == $a) {
        return 0;
    }
    if($a > $b['id']) {
        return 1;
    }

    return -1;
});
var_dump($result);
```

and the result

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(1234)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(12345)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(8)
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(123456)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(123456)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(11)
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(123456)
  }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly what I was trying to achieve, but I wanted to use `array_uintersect` because of the intersect word in the function name (want to make it as clear as possible what I'm doing).

Comment: From the docs `array_uintersect — Computes the intersection of arrays, compares data by a callback function` So I think `array_uintersect` is less clear because of the documentation your not comparing "data". `array_intersect_ukey` does what you want but doesn't return the result that you want. it doesn't combine the values.

Comment: I do want to compare values, not keys. Specifically, I have a multi dimensional array with two subelements (id and timestamp) on every element, and a single dimensional array (only id), and my goal is to discard all the entries from the multi dimensional array that doesn't contain elements from the single dimensional array.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac So you want to compare values, or just rearrange arrays in manner of this answer? Why you trying to perform intersect, when your arrays intersection are empty? You're printing some hidden details of algorithm implementation, not the function result

Comment: Ok I think i understand now, so you have an array with objects that have an `id` and some other properties and you have a array with `ids` and you want to filter all objects that aren't defined in the array that contains the `ids`

Comment: That's it. and I know there are million ways to do this, but I wanted to use intersection cause of the function name. I mean, intersection literally means keeping only elements that share a property.

Comment: I did it! not sure if stable :P see updated answer. Note that this isn't the most efficient way to do it. but it's with the intersection method ;)

Comment: Needs more improvements because where `-1` is returned is incorrectly (should return 1 or -1)

Comment: And updated again with the correct returns ;) should be pretty stable now

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php
    $i  = 0;
    $r1 = ['foo', 'bar'];
    $r2 = ['baz', 'qux'];
    $result = array_uintersect($r1, $r2, function($a, $b){
        return ($a[0]> $b[0]);
    });


    var_dump($result);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
      1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Comment: Could use some explaining.