# PHP: array_uintersect() unexpected input params

Tags: php, arrays, callback

Recently came across function [array_uintersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php). Just wondering if any one can explain how input params are passed as I got the unexpected inputs passed to callback function, I have already went through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288922/php-array-uintersect-unexpected-behaviour) answer but couldn't find answer to my question. Any help or leads will be appreciated, Just trying to understand working of call back function.

NOTE: RESULT OF FUNCTION IS PERFECTLY FINE.

Code:

```
function myfunction($a,$b) {
    echo "$a -- $b \n";
    if ($a===$b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a>$b)?1:-1;
}

$a1 = array(1,2,3);
$a2 = array(4,5,1);
$result = array_uintersect($a1,$a2,"myfunction");
print_r($result);
```

As we are passing both the arrays as parameters,expected the inputs to be values from each array where as got below result.

Result:

```
1 -- 2
2 -- 3
4 -- 5
5 -- 1
4 -- 1
1 -- 1
1 -- 2
2 -- 4
3 -- 4
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

Comment: Without looking at the PHP code, I would say there are two sets of results, the first one from where it is sorting `$a1` and `$a2` (up to `4 -- 1`) and the second from where it is comparing them. But that is exactly what was said in the linked question, so what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nick mention in his comment (and also the link you shared) claim that `array_uintersect` sort the arrays before checking for intersect.

This will be the part of:

```
1 -- 2 // sort first array
2 -- 3 // sort first array
4 -- 5 // sort second array
5 -- 1 // sort second array
4 -- 1 // sort second array
```

Now both array are: `$a1 = [1,2,3] and $a2 = [1,4,5]`.

Now the intersection part:

```
1 -- 1  // checking index 0 in both array
1 -- 2  // checking $a2[0] and $a1[1] -> 2 is bigger so let continue with him
2 -- 4  // checking $a1[1] and $a2[1] -> as we already check $a2[0] -> 4 is bigger so continue with him
3 -- 4  // checking $a1[2] and $a2[1] -> 4 is bigger but not $a1[3] so done checking
```

Notice the intersection can be done in `O(n)`because of the sort that done before...